# prepend using orderBy in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

as you can see by using push, the item is inserted as last item in the list, how can I prepend it?

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/2875/

```
$scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todoText, done:false});
```

I'm confused for the 2nd argument in here : `orderBy : **'some_id'** : reverse`

some_id can be a var in js right?

Comment: So, you want to push items to the first position?

Comment: @ling.s yes. I once did it but it has conflict with my backend. I rather do the sort in front-end to avoid heavy request in the back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the unshift() method on the array to add a item at the beginning

```
$scope.todos.unshift({text:$scope.todoText, done:false});
```

About unshift:  The unshift() method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and returns the new length of the array

DEMO: [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vGLc7/)

Source: [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

Comment: so it's just replace push by unshift?

Comment: yeah, you have to use the unshift method instead of push method. I have provided a demo, check it out @user3277912.

Comment: thx so much.. but it doesn't solve my problem. I load my backend and list become unsorted. look like I hv to do backend sort and bring it back to the front, is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$scope.addTodo = function() {
  $scope.todos.unshift({text:$scope.todoText, done:false});
  $scope.todoText = '';
};
```

Here is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/2876/)